# Core Data or Sqlite with FMDB for RSS Feed Based Application?

Tags: iphone, core-data

hii friends,

My application based on RSS Feeds where i have to use database  for offline support

which is the apt approach either by using Core Data or Sqlite,

i read this article

http://inessential.com/2010/02/26/on_switching_away_from_core_data

Lets puts this in your View?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That article describes a singular situation where Core Data did not benefit his application design. It is the exception that proves the rule.

Core Data should be your first option for any application that persists data on iOS.  FMDB, while useful before Core Data was available on iOS, is not nearly as powerful as Core Data nor does it provide you with all of the performance and memory benefits.

Stick with Core Data.

Answer (score 1):

Going with anything other than CoreDate would be premature optimisation - unless you know you are going to store tens of thousands of objects, and iterate over them in a timely fashion, then I see no reason not to use CoreData.